# How to limit speed for some users with apache?

Tags: php, linux, apache, web

I'm just wondering if there is any apache web server module that supports limiting speed with the option of adding specific IP/user account to an allow list for a none-throttled speed...

Answer (score 1):

Really disappointed with the OP. A 2 second google search revealed this.

```
<Location /downloads>
    SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
    SetEnv rate-limit 400 
</Location>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ratelimit.html

Comment: But note that `mod_ratelimit` is only available under Apache 2.4, which is not in wide use yet. Similar modules (like `mod_bw`) exist for earlier versions.

Comment: I use Apache 2.4 on all my development and production servers. No reason not too. It's faster, uses less memory and is better in just about every way.